# Migration from groovy script to painless scriptin ElasticSearch 5.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-painless

I have been using a groovy Script as ScriptType.File. A part of my groovy Script looks like this.

```
def refApplicValues =_source.refApplicValue;
def lineNumbers = refApplicValues.tokenize('|');
```

Now Im migrating to ElasticSearch 5.2.1 which uses painless script.I have modified my script a bit to match painless syntax like:

```
def refApplicValues =params._source.refApplicValue;
def lineNumbers = refApplicValues.tokenize('|');
```

When i run my script now its throwing runtime error:

```
Caused by: QueryPhaseExecutionException[Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Unable to find dynamic method [tokenize] with [1] arguments for class [java.lang.String].];
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:405)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$9.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:322)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$9.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:319)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:610)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:596)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Its telling me that i cant use tokenize . Is there any relevant functionality that can be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) in painless